# SQL Server performance with FREEPROCCACHE

Tags: sql-server, performance

I watched a lesson on Youtube about SQL Server performance tuning. They demonstrated on a query "Wait Time per Core Per Sec". They use an update script as below:

```
DBCC TRACEON(4199,-1);

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

Go
```

Can anybody explain this script? I used SQL Server 2017.

My question: Is it a benefit when I apply this script to improve the performance?

Comment: No you don't benefit from this. Trace flag 4199 in on by default from SQL Server 2016 onwards. FREEPROCCACHE clears the plan cache, this is useful when you want to ensure you generate a new plan, it's not a performance switch. Check out the MS Docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-freeproccache-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Do you know the way to improve query performance ? pls

Comment: generally, or you have 1 specific query causing you pain?

Comment: The script does not tune the query; its intent is to measure performance. Generally one improves performance by examining the execution plan and performing query and index tuning.

Answer (score 2):

Before SQL Server 2016 you needed the trace flag to enable query optimizer fixes from previous SQL Server versions. 
Since SQL Server 2016 these fixes from previous versions are applied by default and TF 4199 will enable query optimizer fixes that are released in CUs and SPs (but since you are using SQL Server 2017, SPs aren't applicable to you).

Enabling the TF might enhance performance, but it might do the exact opposite for certain queries as well. Different behavior from the QO can result in different execution plans and thus different performance.

Since SQL Server 2016 you can enable the optimizer fixes on a database level by setting the `QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES` database option.

For a specific query you can test the performance by using the query hint `ENABLE_QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES` or by using `QUERYTRACEON`.

In general, don't expect a major difference by setting the TF on or off. Instead you should start by tuning your queries and indexes.